# Active Record Placeholder/Subset conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following query:

```
Score.where("build_id => ? AND metric_id => ? ",params[:buildIds], params[:metricIds])
```

where params[:buildIds], params[:metricIds] are arrays of integers.
I get this error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer => integer
LINE 1: SELECT "scores".* FROM "scores"  WHERE (build_id => 1,2 AND ...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "scores".* FROM "scores"  WHERE (build_id => 1,2 AND metric_id => 1,13 )
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: That's not valid syntax. What do you expect it to do? Perhaps you want to create an array of values and see whether another value is in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to chain two `where` calls together and let ActiveRecord figure out what SQL is needed:

```
Score.where(:build_id => params[:buildIds]).where(:metric_id => params[:metricIds])
```

That will generate `IN`s in the SQL for you so the database should see something like this:

```
where build_id in (1, 2) and metric_id in (1, 13)
```

The error message is telling you that there is no `=>` operator in PostgreSQL with integers on both sides. That's because `=>` is Ruby syntax, not PostgreSQL syntax (unless, of course, you have hstore installed and hstore's `=>` wants strings on both sides).